# Is there a way to edit an Excel spreadsheet embedded in a Word document using Python?

Tags: python, excel, ms-word

I would like to edit an Excel table embedded in a Word document with Python (3.10.13).

I was able to edit all tables / texts of the Word document using `from docx import Document`, but I was not able to access the embedded Excel table.

I am quite new to the subject, so apart from the following approaches I have not been able to come up with much (so far):

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document(complete_file_path)
#....
for table in doc.tables:
  print(table)

#or
#....
for shape in doc.inline_shapes:
  print(shape)
```

My main problem is that I simply cannot find the table (`doc.tables` and `doc.inline_shapes` have no elements => loop is skipped).

This problem exists both with my real "template" Word file, as well as in a simple and quick to create dummy Word document with an Excel table integrated (Insert => Tables => Excel spreadsheet)

Comment: Seems like editing Excel data has been requested [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/1141) and [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/560). The documentation mentions editing tables but not Excel tables. It looks like this is not supported yet (with this library at least).

Comment: Microsoft has defined a document within a document structure to allow each app to work with its native structures.  Not sure how to pick that apart.

Comment: I assume that I could edit the Excel table with `openpyxl` as soon as I find it in the Word document. If there was a way to edit the Excel table separately and then integrate it specifically into the Word file (e.g. "Insert table1 of the Excel file "to_be_embedded.xlsx" in line 15 from A1 to C10 or similar), I would also be interested.  (Even if I would prefer direct editing.)

Comment: Just to be on the safe side:
It is currently neither possible to edit the cells of an Excel table within a Word document, nor to insert an existing Excel table into a Word document? A hint in the right direction (if there is one) would be enough for me...

Comment: I think you can edit the Excel table if you're using the actual Microsoft apps to do it, so theoretically you could also do it from outside.  Unfortunately I can't give you anything beyond that since I've never done it.  You might search for "compound document" though, I think that's the name they used for the feature.

Comment: @MarkRansom Have I perhaps posted my question in the wrong forum? I would like to completely automate the invoicing process. The last step (inserting the updated Excel table into the updated Word document) is currently still done "by hand" (copy & paste cell values). This solution is not practicable and can only be used for test purposes. For me, Microsoft Apps are application programs that enable manual/personal editing of files. This is exactly what I would like to avoid. If I have misunderstood something, I am sorry: please go into a little more detail.

Comment: I am only telling you that I personally don't know how to automate it.  That doesn't mean it's impossible, just that I can't help you.  I was hoping that giving you another search term might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no direct way to edit an Excel table within a Word document.

My solution is therefore as follows:

Instead of editing a contained Excel table, I edit and save the Excel table separately and insert it in the place of a placeholder using `win32com`:

```
import win32com.client

def insert_Excel_table_into_Word_document(full_doc_path, full_excel_path):
    # Open Word application
    word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    # Open Word document
    word_doc = word_app.Documents.Open(full_doc_path)

    # Search for the placeholder in the document
    find_str = "[excel_table]"
    search_range = word_doc.Content
    search_range.Find.Execute(find_str)

    if search_range.Find.Found:
        search_range.Text = ""
        # Placeholder found, insert Excel table
        search_range.Collapse(0) 
        
        excel_range = search_range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(
            ClassType="Excel.Sheet",
            FileName=full_excel_path,
            LinkToFile=False,
            DisplayAsIcon=False
        )

        # Adjust the Excel table width so that the page margins 
        # of the Word document (if exceeded) are no longer exceeded
        page_width = word_doc.PageSetup.PageWidth - (word_doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin
                                                     + word_doc.PageSetup.RightMargin)
        if excel_range.Width > page_width:
            excel_range.Width = page_width - 10

    else:
        print("No placeholder found.")

    # Save Word document
    # new_doc_path = r"some\different_path\if\you_want\different_save_file"
    # word_doc.SaveAs(new_doc_path)
    # otherwise:
    word_doc.Save()

    word_doc.Close()
    word_app.Quit()
```

`full_doc_path` or `full_excel_path` correspond to the complete file path of the respective Word or Excel file.
`[excel_table]` is the placeholder and must be contained in the body text of the Word document (not somehow nested)

Remarks:
Even if "theoretically" `win32com` should be able to find the Excel table within the Word document:
In my case, an object was found (`docx` found none), but it was not recognized as an Excel table and could not be opened as such, even if this Excel table was previously inserted by `win32com`.
I continue to use `docx` and `openpyxl` to edit the Word and Excel file before inserting it. `win32com` seems to be much slower and I had already coded the editing using `docx` and `openpyxl`.

Comment: Typing errors caused by my translation (German => English) have been corrected. The function should now work perfectly. Would be nice if someone could test this for other systems. I only want to publish answers that are generally valid.